# How do I center the middle item in a list

Tags: html, css

I have a list with three items. The logo, title, social icons. How do I center the 2nd item in the list

This is my HMTL5

```css
.menu {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  width: 40px;
  fill: pink;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="{{asset('img/menu.svg')}}" class="icon"></li>
    <li>
      <p>The Financial Clue</p>
    </li>
    <li>Social Icons</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "center"?

Comment: Is it always a `<p>`?

Comment: Do you want to center it vertically, horizontally, or both?

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. Add following code into the styles:

```
.menu ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use text-align:center to center the text and vertical-align:middle so that your list items will be centered horizontally. Advisable to give your parent/li a width value so that the text-align has a width to center within.

Hope this helps

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  width: 40px;
  fill: pink;
}


ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="{{asset('img/menu.svg')}}" class="icon"></li>
    <li>
      <p>The Financial Clue</p>
    </li>
    <li>Social Icons</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to center all of the items in the list that can be simply done using the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), the space-between value will evenly distribute the values along the row.

```
.menu ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

If you mean to center the middle list item to align with the other two items in the list, the `<p>` tags will add extra padding around the text, so you may want to remove that unless there is a valid reason for it to be there.

Answer (score -1):

---1st option would be just to set the Code : `align-items: center;`  or just `align: center;` in your style.css---

```
.menu {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  width: 40px;
  fill: pink;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---- 2nd option is just to try through HTML to use the code `<center> - </center>` between all the items that you want. --- (If is HTML5 it may work straight with center code.---

```
 <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="{{asset('img/menu.svg')}}" class="icon"></li>
        <li>
          <p>The Financial Clue</p>
        </li>
        <li> 
         <center>
           <h3>Social Icons<h3>
         </center>
       </li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

//* if this is your main title of the menu, you can use the code to make it center *//
//* I've used H3 as i guess the text should show smaller, you can change it to h1 as main and after just resize it with size code. *//

Comment: It's not even deprecated, it is [**Obsolete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) one day you wake up and a new chrome version comes and sees that this tag is not working anymore.